# Comparing Two Words(Strings)

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

What does this code mean?

```
if( item.compareTo(root.element) < 0 ){

   }
```

I read that:

> "Compares two strings lexicographically. Returns an integer indicating
>   whether this string is greater than (result is > 0), equal to (result
>   is = 0), or less than (result is < 0) the argument."

But I don't don't get it. Can someone explain with an example please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation of the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, which defines the [`compareTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method in the first place. The implementation of this interface in `String` follows the same conventions:

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object

This means: if the current string is *less than* the string received as parameter (under the [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)) return a negative integer value. If the current string is *greater than* the string received as parameter, return a positive integer value. Otherwise, the strings are equal and `0` is returned.

Comment: How does it determine which String is greater?

Comment: Using ["lexicographical order"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), that is: if a string "a" appears before other string "b" in a dictionary, then it's said that "a" is less than "b".

Comment: Lexicographically (i.e. alphabetically). I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: @AdegokeA "How does it determine which String is greater?" Java compares String characters using its position in [Unicode table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). After sorting you will get for example something like this `12, 3, Aa, BB, a, bb, ńŇ, Ňń`

Answer (score 2):

You would use this in sorting code to see if `item` belongs before `root.element` or not.

Comment: Is that in sorting alphabetically?

Comment: Yes... If item and root are strings. Every class that implements the `Comparable` interface must define the `compareTo` method, giving it semantics that make sense for that class.

Comment: @jpm described it perfectly - in general, yes it probably is alphabetical order, but it really depends on what the implementor of the compareTo does in their implementation!

Answer (score 2):

it checks if two Strings are equal like this.

```
a>A  would return a positive number as `a` is greater than `A`
A>a  would return a negetive number as `A` is less than `a`
a==a would return 0 as `a` is equal to `a`
a>Z  would return a positive number as 'a' is greater than 'A'
trend> zend would return a positive number as `t` is greater than 'z'
```

Comment: This is not correct:  _compareTo_ does not necessarily return `-1`, `0`, or `1`.  It returns `a negative number`, `zero`, or `a positive number`.  For example `"A".compareTo("a")` returns -32.

Comment: No problem.  The actual values returned by those comparisons are: `-32, 32, 0, 7, -6`.  This gives a little insight as to how the values are calculated.

Comment: @jahroy so, they'd basically return ascii values . am i right ??

Comment: For a simple one character comparison you will get something very similar to the difference in the ascii values.  If you compare strings, the value and position of each character is taken into account (I believe).  For `trend and zend` it looks like it finds the first difference and doesn't care what happens afterward.  I'm playing with it now in a test program, which is very easy to do.

Comment: @jahroy awesome mahn.. and again thanks for letting meknow, i always tought its -1, 1 , 0 return .. haha.. :)

Comment: When I write my own compareTo I usually get lazy and return `-1` or `1` for things that aren't equal.  I bet others do the same.  **BUT** we aren't required (or advised) to be so lazy.  However, such laziness probably gets the job done most of the time.  For example, I usually start my _compareTo_ methods with a line that looks like this:  `if (otherObject == null) return -1`.  This sorts null objects after non-null ones. (_for the record I did not down-vote you... I up-voted you after you edited_).

Comment: @jahroy true that, i have indeed seen some legacy code in my app with such approach.. :)

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR "so, they'd basically return ascii values . am i right" You are close, but its index of Unicode table not ASCII. Check this out `"+".compareTo("➯"` returns `-10116` since `+` in Unicode is indexed as `U+002B (hex) = 43 (dec)`, `➯` is indexed as `27AF (hex) =  10159 (dec)`. Value returned is simple difference between Unicode indexes (43 - 10159 = 10116).

Comment: @Pshemo thank you for the info, i have learned a lot today from answering this question :), as you can see from my prev comments :)

Answer (score 2):

**someObject**.*compareTo*(**anotherObject**) returns a negative number if *someObject* comes before *anotherObject*.

Here's an example that compares String objects:

```
if ("apple".compareTo("zebra") < 0) {
    System.out.println("I will be printed");
}
else {
    System.out.println("I will NOT be printed");
}
```

Comment: As in x, y, z? Or x equals a String? If x is a String, is it calculating alphabetically?

Comment: @AdegokeA - I edited my answer so it (hopefully) makes more sense.  To answer your question: Yes, if the objects are strings, the comparison is made alphabetically.  If the objects are not strings, the behavior is defined by the way that _compareTo_ is implemented by the class in question.  This is the beauty of the _Comparable_ interface.  Any object can implement it **AND** any object that implements it can be sorted and compared (without knowing the details of how it works).

Answer (score 2):

If the word1= item, and word2= root.element and both are in a dictionary, word1 should appear before word2.